# how to run bash for loop and using GNU parallel?

Tags: bash, for-loop, gnu-parallel

I have a bash loop where I am passing variables to a script. I want to run these in parallel with GNU parallel

```bash
for FILE_NAME in FILE1 FILE2 FILE3; 
do
    ./SCRIPT -n $FILE_NAME
done
```

where I want the scripts to run in parallel as follows:

```bash
     ./SCRIPT -n FILE1
     ./SCRIPT -n FILE2
     ./SCRIPT -n FILE3
```

I am trying to use the GNU parallel command because it has been suggested a lot on here, but I am confused about where to put the parallel command if I am passing a variable to the script.

I have tried turning the `FILE1 FILE2 FILE3` into a list:

```bash
parallel -a $FILE_LIST ./SCRIPT -n $FILE_NAME
```

```bash
for FILE_NAME in FILE1 FILE2 FILE3; 
do
    parallel ./SCRIPT -n $FILE_NAME
done
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
parallel ./SCRIPT -n {} ::: FILE1 FILE2 FILE3
```

Or, more succinctly if your files are really named like that:

```
parallel ./SCRIPT -n {} ::: FILE*
```